# Rxjs Observable stops after emitting first value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a toggle button in my UI which start/stops transports. The button triggers this onSubmit() method

```
onSubmit() {
  this.transportService.currentTransport$.pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap((status) => {
      if (status) {
        return this.transportService.completeTransport$();
      } else {
        return this.transportService.startTransport$(this.transportForm.value);
      }
    }))
    .subscribe({
      next: (transport) => {
        this.startedTransport.emit('started')
      },
      error: err => {
        this.isTransportAlertOpen = true;
        this.errorMessage = 'check connection';
      },
    })
}
```

it checks wether there is a transport currently being fulfilled. If that is not the case, a new transport is started with the startTransport$() method of the transportService. If there already is a transport the current transport gets completed with completeTransport$(). Both of these methods do some calls to the backend. I subscribe to the observables to handle errors and open another modal. This works as I expected...

**Now instead of using a button** to trigger the start/stop of the transport I need to integrate a sensor that constantly emits values of its loaded state (loaded=true/false) and start the transport based on the loaded state.

I tried the following in the ngOnInit method of my component. I use the skip operator to ignore the defaul value that gets emittet by the sensorStatus$ Observable.

```
  this.sensor.sensorStatus$.pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('BLE Sensor Emission')),
    skip(1),
    switchMap((sensor) => {
      return this.transportService.currentTransport$.pipe(
        take(1),
        switchMap((currentTransport) => {
          if (currentTransport && !sensor.isLoaded) {
            return this.transportService.completeTransport$();
          }
          if (sensor.isLoaded && !currentTransport) {
            return this.transportService.startTransport$(this.transportForm.value);
          }
          return of(null);
        }));
    }))
    .subscribe({
      next: (transport) => {
        this.startedTransport.emit('started')
      },
      error: err => {
        this.isTransportAlertOpen = true;
        this.errorMessage = 'Verbindung mit Zigpos überprüfen';
      },
      complete: () => console.warn('Completed')
    })
}
```

I am using almost the same implementation as previously but for some reason this only triggers after the first loaded-emission from the sensor. After that, nothing is happening.

I already checked the sensor observable and it is constantly emitting values as expected so that isnt the problem. The observable in the ngOnInit also doesnt complete which would stop any further emissions. So I guess that the error has to be somewhere in my implementation of the nested switchMaps. Any suggestions what could be the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that with ```switchMap``` you are returning observable from transportService that is short live observable and subscribing to it, so it's logical that will only emit once. You want to subscribe to sensorStatus$ that is emitting value from sensor but to have side effects to call when sensor emit value. Why don't you do those calls inside of ```subscribe``` of sensorStatus$ observable?

Comment: That makes sense, I am going to reafctor some code and try to implement the sideeffects differently. regarding your second point: I think then I would have to do nested subscriptions because I also need to subscribe to the observables from the transport service because otherwise the requests to BE arent executed

Comment: If you have something like that you can try and use ```combineLatest``` from RxJs i think that should help you.

Comment: I'm curious as to what `this.transportService.currentTransport$` looks like.  I'm thinking some change is causing it to close and that is why you no longer get any more messages.